# Getting object releation ship in salesforce objects

Tags: salesforce

I need to get the list of oppurtunities associated with a salesforce user. But I don't know the relationship between user object and oppurtunities object.

How do I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "Opportunities associated to a salesforce User", I am assuming that you want a list of opportunities where a salesforce owner is a owner of the opportunity records.
You could do this:

```
user u = [select id, name from user where id='put the user id here'];
list<opportunity> listOfOpportunity = [select id, name from opportunity where ownerId=: u.Id];
```

There are other ways a user can be associated to a opportunity: createdBy and lastmodifiedBy.. Also you can have your custom loopup to User object

Hope it helps

Comment: Yeah its just a query.. You can open the developer console, go to Query editor , paste only the query in the edit and execute the query. You will see the results